# Do these two functions have proper names?

Tags: functions, summation, terminology, products

I need a descriptive name for these two functions, for a program's interface ; and I'm having trouble describing them properly. I'm looking either for an established conventional name, or a good suggestion for one.

Let $E$ be a list of $n$ numbers $\in \mathbb{R}$, let x $\in \mathbb{R}$ :

- $f(x, E) = x\left(1 +\sum{E}\right)$
- $g(x, E) = x(1 + E_1) \cdots (1 + E_n)$

I'm sure there's a simple way to describe them, but everything I have tried so far comes up short. My best guess is currently "Additive Product Addition" for $f$ and "Multiplicative product addition" for $g$ : In each case, we add the product of the elements of $E$ and $x$ to $x$, $f$ stacking additively, $g$ stacking multiplicatively.

Comment: What is the significance of $x$ and $1$ in your functions? $x$ just seems to be multiplying everything. Also why $1+\sum E$?

Comment: Why do you need to give them names? What's wrong with defining $f = \ldots$, and then to refer to it as $f$? You can even use the formula as it is, if the interface allows it. If you think that the name will be of any help to the user, I don't agree with that.

Comment: I didn't define those functions myself. The idea is that for each value in $E$, $x$ is adjusted by the fraction of $x$ it represents. So, if $1 \in E$, x is effectively doubled, and if $-1 \in E$ x is reduced to 0. They are actually composed in the actual program, $Y = g(f(x))$